# How to check the output of a command is empty in bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to automate some git tasks.

I need to check the output of this command to see if it's empty or not:

```
git status --porcelain
```

In Linux, I can use this command:

```
if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then
    // I know it's not empty
fi
```

However, in CMD I don't know how to check it.

Comment: `git status --porcelain |findstr . && echo output || echo emty`. But first I'd check if the command gives a proper `%errorlevel%`

Comment: @Stephan, can you send your comment as an answer and explain it please? Thank you.

Comment: Done. Let me know when you need any deeper explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch's method to get the output of a command (line by line) is a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('command') do echo %%a
```

But it's even easier in your case: Execute the command and filter the output. `.` is `findstr`'s wildcard for "any character" (`findstr` supports a very limited subset of REGEX).

`&&` and `||` are conditional executing: `&&` means "execute the following command only if the previous command was successful" (`findstr` found at least one character), `||` is the exact opposite: "execute the following command only if the previous command (! still the `findstr` command, not the conditional `echo` !) failed (`findstr` didn't find a single character)"

```
git status --porcelain |findstr . && echo output || echo emty.
```

If you are lucky, `git` gives you an `errorlevel` (a sort of "return code"), which usually is zero for a successful command and non-zero for anything else. (To use the errorlevel like this is completely the choice of the programmer - most do, some do not), which you can use like this:

```
git status --porcelain
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo failed
) else (
   echo successful
)
```

Comment: The point is that in this particular case, git returns 0 for both having the output and not having the output. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Is it possible to set a variable instead of `echo output` or `echo empty`? I tried `set HasChanges=true` and it did not work.

Comment: There are two reasons why it could fail: a) you have the code within a code block, where you'd need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) b) you have a trailing space; use recommended `set` syntax to avoid them: `set "var=value"` (note the quotes and their location) If you still have problems, expand your question with your new code.

Comment: (see my comment on [your other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1723112/how-to-fix-this-git-automation-script)