# How to fix this git automation script?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, git

I have this simple script to automate `git status` for a lot of git repositories:

```
@ECHO OFF

for /D %%s in (C:\Projects\*) do (
    set HasChangesCommand=git -C %%s status --porcelain | findstr . && echo 1 || echo 0
    set IsAheadCommand=git -C %%s status --porcelain | findstr ahead && echo 1 || echo 0
    set IsDiveregedCommand=git -C %%s status --porcelain | findstr diverged && echo 1 || echo 0
    if "%HasChangesCommand%" == "1" (
        call Info %%s;
        git -C %%s status --porcelain
        echo.
    ) else if "%IsAheadCommand%" == "1" (
        call Warning Push %%s
    ) else if "%IsDiveregedCommand%" == "1" (
        call Warning Sync %%s
    )
    call Info %HasChanges%
)
```

Basically I want to analyze the output of `git status` for each directory and based on the output I want to show simpler messages.

But it does not work.

I guess I have a problem in running the commands for `if else` blocks.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Remove `echo off` and make sure your variables are set correctly

Comment: I removed `echo off` but it's still not working.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to magically make it work, it was supposed to show you why it is not working.

Comment: @user1686, there is no error at all. It just prints `0` all the way down. That's what I mean by *it's not working*. There are no errors. But the logic is not correct.

Comment: `git -C %%s status --porcelain | findstr . && set "HasChangesCommand=1" || set "HasChangesCommand=0"` and you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) within the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems:

1. The way Cmd.exe works, all variables in the entire `do ( ... )` are expanded *at once,* as if it were just a one-line command – the expansion is not actually repeated for each iteration. This means that any changes made using `set` will have no effect.

   You would need to use delayed expansion using `!var!` or rewrite the loop to `call` a :subroutine instead of a direct `(...)` block.

   (Even better, rewrite the script in PowerShell or Bash or another language that does not have this problem in the first place.)
2. You're not putting the 'git' commands' output in the variable – you're putting the commands *themselves* in the variable. For example, `"%HasChangesCommand%:` contains the literal text `"git -C project1 status..."` which of course will never compare equal to `"0"`.

   To capture a command's output in a variable, you would need to use `for /f` in Cmd, or `$(…)` in Sh/Bash shells. For example:

   ```
   Cmd:     for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('git -C project1 status') do set HasChangesResult=%%a

   Bash:    HasChangesResult=$(git -C project1 status && echo 0 || echo 1)
   ```

   Though in this case, you really don't need the output as you can just directly get the exit status via `%ERRORLEVEL%` in Cmd (or similarly `$?` in Bash):

   ```
   Cmd:     git -C project1 status
            set HasChangesResult=%ERRORLEVEL%

   Bash:    git -C project1 status
            HasChangesResult=$?
   ```
3. Related to the previous problem, operators like `||` are still treated as operators even if they're used in the same line as `set=` – they do not literally become part of the value. For example, this command:

   ```
   set HasChangesCommand=git -C %%s status --porcelain | findstr . && echo 1 || echo 0
   ```

   can be (mentally) grouped as:

   ```
   (set HasChangesCommand=git -C %%s status --porcelain | findstr .)
   && echo 1
   || echo 0
   ```

   In other words, echo is invoked because the `set` command succeeds.

Comment: I appreciate your time. But after reading your explanation for a couple of times, I still can't set a simple variable. Because `%ERRORLEVEL%` is the same for `git status` I can't use it. I need to set a variable and check it. Based on your explanation I tried `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('git -C %%s status --porcelain | findstr . && echo 1 || echo 0') do set HasChangesResult=%%a` but it does not work.

Comment: Can you help me only set those three variables? I'm just stuck there.